# Failing test as a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am running through some exercises and run into this on codewars. Its a simple exercise with Instructions  to create a function called shortcut to remove all the lowercase vowels in a given string.
Examples:

```
shortcut("codewars") // --> cdwrs
shortcut("goodbye")  // --> gdby
```

I am newbie so I thought up this solution. but it doesn't work and I have no idea why

```
function shortcut(string){
  // create an array of individual characters
  var stage1 = string.split('');  

  // loop through array and remove the unneeded characters
  for (i = string.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (stage1[i] === "a"|| 
      stage1[i] === "e"|| 
      stage1[i] === "i"||
      stage1[i] === "o"||
      stage1[i] === "u") {
    stage1.splice(i,1)
    ;}
  };

  // turn the array back into a string
    string = stage1.join('');
    return shortcut;
}
```

My gut is telling me that it will probably something to like split and join not creating "true" array's and strings.

I did it at first with a regex to make it a little more reusable but that was a nightmare. I would be happy to take suggestions on other methods of acheiving the same thing.

Comment: Why is a reg exp bad? seems pretty simple and requires no loop

Comment: If you decide to give RegExp a try: `"codewars".replace(/[aeiou]/gi, "");`.

Comment: sorry ignore. figured this out like 30 seconds after posting....

    return string

Comment: "*it doesn't work*" is a bit vague. In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: og, I can't believe I went through all that and .replace(regex) is such an obvious solution. 
I was still looping just using reg ex as the if conditional.

Thank you guys

Like I said, newbie!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex:

```js
var str = 'codewars';

var regex = /[aeiou]/g;

var result = str.replace(regex, '');

document.write(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

You are returning the function itself, instead of returning `string`

Answer (score 1):

if interested in Regular Expression ;)

```
function shortcut(str) {
    return str.replace(/[aeiou]/g, "");
}
```